# find the best way for factorial in python?

Tags: python, factorial

I am researching on speed of factorial. But I am using two ways only,

```
import timeit

def fact(N):
    B = N
    while N > 1:
        B = B * (N-1)
        N = N-1
    return B

def fact1(N):
    B = 1
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        B = B * i
    return B


print timeit.timeit('fact(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact"), fact(5)
print timeit.timeit('fact1(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact1"), fact1(5)
```

Here is the output,

```
0.540276050568 120
0.654400110245 120
```

From above code I have observed,

1. While take less time than for

My question is,

Is the best way to find the factorial in python ?

Comment: Use a larger number N so you are testing the loop and not the function overhead.

Comment: Why do `N-1` twice? You can swap those two lines and save one subraction

Comment: Do you want to find a more effective algorithm ?

Comment: @yes atupal. I want much effective algorithm

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking for the best, why not use the one provided in the math module?

```
>>> import math
>>> math.factorial
<built-in function factorial>
>>> math.factorial(10)
3628800
```

And a comparison of timings on my machine:

```
>>> print timeit.timeit('fact(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact"), fact(5)
0.840167045593 120
>>> print timeit.timeit('fact1(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact1"), fact1(5)
1.04350399971 120
>>> print timeit.timeit('factorial(5)', setup="from math import factorial")
0.149857997894
```

We see that the builtin is significantly better than either of the pure python variants you proposed.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; microbenchmarks aren't very useful

For Cpython, try this:

```
>>> from math import factorial


>>> print timeit.timeit('fact(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact"), fact(5)
1.38128209114 120
>>> print timeit.timeit('fact1(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact1"), fact1(5)
1.46199703217 120
>>> print timeit.timeit('factorial(5)', setup="from math import factorial"), factorial(5)
0.397044181824 120
```

But under pypy, the `while` is faster than the one from `math`

```
>>>> print timeit.timeit('fact(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact"), fact(5)\
0.170556783676 120
>>>> print timeit.timeit('fact1(5)', setup="from __main__ import fact1"), fact1\
(5)
0.319650173187 120
>>>> print timeit.timeit('factorial(5)', setup="from math import factorial"), f\
actorial(5)
0.210616111755 120
```

So it depends on the implementation. Now try bigger numbers

```
>>>> print timeit.timeit('fact(50)', setup="from __main__ import fact"), fact(50)
7.71517109871 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
>>>> print timeit.timeit('fact1(50)', setup="from __main__ import fact1"), fact1(50)
6.58060312271 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
>>>> print timeit.timeit('factorial(50)', setup="from math import factorial"), factorial(50)
6.53072690964 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
```

`while` is in last place, and the version using `for` is about the same as the one from the `math` module

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, if you're looking for a Python implementation (*this is my favourite*):

```
from operator import mul


def factorial(n):
    return reduce(mul, range(1, (n + 1)), 1)
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> factorial(0)
1
>>> factorial(1)
1
>>> factorial(2)
2
>>> factorial(3)
6
>>> factorial(4)
24
>>> factorial(5)
120
>>> factorial(10)
3628800
```

**Performance:** (*On my desktop*:)

```
$ python -m timeit -c -s "fact = lambda n: reduce(lambda a, x: a * x, range(1, (n + 1)), 1)" "fact(10)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with `reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(1, 5))`

```
>>>timeit("import math; math.factorial(4)")
1.0205099133840179

>>>timeit("reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(1, 5))")
1.4047879075160665

>>>timeit("from operator import mul;reduce(mul, range(1, 5))")
2.530837320051319
```